# VSCodeBeautify How to create a config for beautify to prevent text wrap

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

## I am using

- **Windows 10 Ent (Version 10.0.15063 Build 15063)**:
- **VS Code Version 1.32.1**:
- **beautify Version 1.4.9**:

### Action Performed

Trying to configure the settings to prevent Beautify from wrapping my plain text when I use it for HTML files (because I have VSC set up to already wrap my text). [Documentation](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify) isn't clear on how to do this.

```
settings.json:
{
     "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation",
    "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "window.restoreWindows": "all",
    "beautify.config": "C:\\User\\Scorchgid\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\setting.jsbeautifyrc",
}
```

```
setting.jsbeautifyrc
{
    "wrap_line_length": 0,
}
```

### Starting code

```
<div>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

### Expected Result

```
<div>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
</div>
```

### Actual results

```
<div>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
        magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
        laborum."</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This reads like a bug report, what is your question? (If it is a bug report, it would be better suited to an issue on the plugin's Github rather than Stack Overflow)

Comment: @DBS I made a bug report. It was ignored. https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/issues/294

Comment: I appreciate it's annoying when something's not working, but I'm afraid there's not much we can do about a bug in a library. Please do bare in mind that lots of plugins are maintained by a single dev as a personal project and it can take time for them to get around to looking at your problem, let alone fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

[This post answered my question](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/issues/294#issuecomment-471938930) Thank you to Galzor

> try inserting below line in your settings.json. let me know if it helps

```
"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0,
```